# can pexpect be used to get the output till timeout without looking for any specific pattern

Tags: python

i have a telnet session spawned. I want to get whatever output the session throws in a given time interval. How to do it using pexpect.
I tried expect('.*',20). But this matches whatever the output has till that time and not waits for the timeout 20 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
# set expected to some string you might not see
def ReadByDuration(connection, expected = ".*", read_time = 20, epsilon = 0.001):
    from time import time
    start_time = time()
    response = connection.read_until(expected,float(read_time))
    time_passed = time() - start_time 
    # if timeout not met, read again
    while read_time - time_passed > epsilon :
        response += connection.read_until(expected, float(read_time  - time_passed))
        time_passed = time() - start_time
    return response
```

and if you want to get really fancy, you can add it to the class functions

```
import telnetlib, types
t = telnetlib.Telnet(IP, PORT, 20)
t.ReadByDuration = types.MethodType( ReadByDuration, t )

t.ReadByDuration(".*", 20)
```